# Multiple DBML models best practice for class names

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql, naming-conventions

Several of our apps use multiple databases from the example below - each in their own separate DBML file. The problem is, MVC by convention puts them all in `namespace AppName.Models` causing class name conflicts.

Which of the two options is the better fix and why:

1.) Putting them in separate namespaces. To keep stylecop/resharper happy, they would go in their own subfolder:

- /Models
- - /Live
- - - Live.dbml
- - - LiveDataContext.cs
- - /Crm
- - - Crm.dbml
- - - CrmDataContext.cs

**but now in code, all uses of them have to be `Live.Customer` and `Crm.Customer` to differentiate between objects.

#### EDIT: The other main downside of this, is that I see no other sample code from experts that use sub folders in the `Models` folder. On top of that, in order to keep the same naming for `Helper` file code reuse - even apps that only use one database would need a subfolder in `Models`, which I certainly never see people doing in MVC

2.) Prepending all object names in one or both DBML designers with a prefix. This is my current approach. The Live database has `Customer` and `Order` objects, while the Crm database has `CrmCustomer` and `CrmOrder`. They all stay in the same namespace and `/Models` folder. This, however has two main drawbacks:

- Quite a bit of prefix redundancy in accessing child objects: `CrmCustomer.CrmOrders.First().CrmOrderType` Marsha Marsha Marsha
- In other apps which only use one database, we often omit the prefix - and then during code reuse or `Helper` files we have to do a lot of find/replace. This is particularly evident in `Helper` files that get added to every app like error/activity logging.

So I'd like to hear from other experts which of the two strategies they use, or something else entirely. It seems like a pretty common occurrence to have at least some name conflicts between databases. Thanks

---

Example table names:

**Live Database:**

- Customer
- Order
- Address
- Phone
- Log
- 20 other tables

**Intranet Database:**

- Customer
- Order
- Address
- Phone
- Log
- 20 other tables

**CRM Tool Database:**

- Customer
- Order
- Address
- Phone
- Log
- 400 other tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I question the design that leads you to needing two identical databases in code. That aside, I think option 1 is better. Here is my reasoning:

1. The code is more reusable. If you ever need to seperate either model into another project, or remove one, you don't have to remove the prefixes anywhere. This offers clean separation.
2. Option 2 requires you to specify as well, you aren't avoiding this. However, if any class needs to access only one namespace, you only need to specify at the `using` level, and not in every single reference to the code. In classes that need both, you aren't avoiding the prefixses in either case. So option #1 wins out in the only case that matters.
3. I generally avoid type-prefixes as a rule. They are ugly.
4. Grumble, grumble, database design

Comment: the database/tables are not actually identical .. but they store the same object type, which is the class name. Live is a transactional database which eventually feeds all activity into a 3rd party CRM database. In code, both have a `Person` object (and an `Address` object, etc).

So moving a person's `Names`,`Addresses`,`Emails`,`Payments`,etc from their source to the CRM, leads to two different objects of the same name. Hope that makes sense

Comment: @arserbin3 Ok, that makes a bit more sense. I maintain all my reasons though. Especially #1.

Comment: The main downside of option 1, is that I see no other sample code from experts that use sub folders in the `Models` folder. On top of that, in order to keep the same naming for `Helper` file code reuse - even apps that only use one database would need a subfolder in `Models`, which I certainly never see people doing in MVC. On an aside, I do currently feel option 1 is the lesser of the two evils

Comment: Neither have I. But I've also never seen anyone try to do what you are doing. So... new problems, new solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you have two additional possible solutions:

1. You can modify the namespace of the entities generated by the DBML. Assuming you use T4 templates to generate them, you can right-click on the *.tt file, and go to properties. There is a namespace property that you can set to your own custom, and therefore unique, namespace:

   - MyCompany.MyProject.DataModels.Live
   - MyCompany.MyProject.DataModels.Intranet
   - MyCompany.MyProject.DataModels.CRM
2. A second, similar option would be to have each dbml and the generated classes be contained in their own project, and their own namespace associated with it. So in this case you would have three new projects:

   - Data.Live
   - Data.Intranet
   - Data.CRM

   You would then add a reference to the projects when you want to consume them.

   The benefit to this, in my opinion, is that it is very likely that tomorrow you could have a project that needs to reference Live, CRM, and a brand new database. In this case you would simply take a dependency on the projects you've already created (binary, or code -- my preference is binary, but YMMV), and that part of this 2nd project is complete.

In my opinion, do not decorate you classes (your option 2). That will be very difficult to maintain.
There is nothing inherently wrong with your option 1, and I have done that as well, but for most of my current solutions I create projects for the reusability factor.